# Pinterest Navigation Bar Box Shadow css

Tags: shadow, css

Does anyone know how to get the exact box shadow that appears on the bottom of the fixed position navbar on pinterest.com?

http://pinterest.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have used any developer tool (Chrome DevTools or Firebug) to find this out:

```css
box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sites CSS styling in Chrome I got this segment of code for that bar:

```css
#CategoriesBar {
position: absolute;
z-index: 101;
top: 44px;
right: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 13px;
color: #8C7E7E;
background-color: #FAF7F7;
border-top: 1px solid #CFCACA;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
}
```

These 3 lines should help you out on your style:

```css
box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #fff, 0 1px 3px rgba(34,25,25,0.4);
```